nested dicts processing with irregular nesting hierarchy
How can one process a pair of nested dicts with partial key overlap?
dict1 = {
    'A': {'a': 1},
    'B': 2,
    'C': {'c': 3},
    'D': {'d': {'dd': 4}}
}

dict2 = {
    'A': {'a': 1},
    'D': {'d': {'dd': 4}}
}

the desired output should be:
dict1 + dict2= {
    'A': {'a': 2},
    'B': 2,
    'C': {'c': 3},
    'D': {'d': {'dd': 8}}
}

A key-wise addition of flat dicts is straightforward:
{k: dict1[k] + dict2[k] for k, v in dict2.items()}

How can I do the same with nested dicts?

What should the output be? We can't help you without the output. For instance, do you want the numbers to be added, or written in a list if keys overlap?

print(dict1['A']['a'])

You could try define a recursive function yourself:
import pprint
from collections.abc import Mapping
from typing import Any


def _pretty_print_labled_mapping(label: str, d: Mapping[Any, Any]) -> None:
  """Pretty print a mapping with a label."""
  print(f'{label}:')
  pprint.pprint(d, indent=2, width=1)


def merge_mappings(*mappings: Mapping[Any, Any]) -> Mapping[Any, Any]:
  """Merges mappings recursively."""
  merged = {}
  for m in mappings:
    for key in m:
      if key in merged:
        if isinstance(merged[key], dict) and isinstance(m[key], dict):
          merged[key] = merge_mappings(merged[key], m[key])
        else:
          merged[key] += m[key]
      else:
        merged[key] = m[key]
  return merged


def main() -> None:
  d1 = {'A': {'a': 1}, 'B': 2, 'C': {'c': 3}, 'D': {'d': {'dd': 4}}}
  _pretty_print_labled_mapping('d1', d1)
  d2 = {'A': {'a': 1}, 'D': {'d': {'dd': 4}}}
  _pretty_print_labled_mapping('d2', d2)
  result = merge_mappings(d1, d2)
  _pretty_print_labled_mapping('result', result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()

Output:
d1:
{ 'A': { 'a': 1},
  'B': 2,
  'C': { 'c': 3},
  'D': { 'd': { 'dd': 4}}}
d2:
{ 'A': { 'a': 1},
  'D': { 'd': { 'dd': 4}}}
result:
{ 'A': { 'a': 2},
  'B': 2,
  'C': { 'c': 3},
  'D': { 'd': { 'dd': 8}}}


note, there is a standard library pprint module for dicts like this, so: import pprint; pprint.pprint(data)

Done. However it seems it is not as "pretty" as what is output from the json module.

You can iterate through a union of keys of all the input dicts to sum the values of keys from dicts that have the keys, or recursively aggregate those values if they aren't summable as numbers (which means they are dicts in your case):
from itertools import chain

def add_nested_dicts(*dicts):
    result = {}
    for key in dict.fromkeys(chain.from_iterable(dicts)):
        values = [d[key] for d in dicts if key in d]
        try:
            result[key] = sum(values)
        except TypeError:
            result[key] = add_nested_dicts(*values)
    return result

so that:
add_nested_dicts(dict1, dict2)

returns:
{'A': {'a': 2}, 'B': 2, 'C': {'c': 3}, 'D': {'d': {'dd': 8}}}

Demo: https://ideone.com/EsnKCS
